# fatal error in php pdf creation don't know what the error

Tags: php

```
<?php
$pdf=pdf_new();
pdf_open_file($pdf, "test.pdf");
pdf_begin_page($pdf, 595, 842);
$arial = pdf_findfont($pdf, "Arial", "host", 1); 
pdf_setfont($pdf, $arial, 10);
pdf_show_xy($pdf, "There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,",50, 750);
pdf_end_page($pdf);
pdf_show_xy($pdf, "than are dreamt of in your philosophy", 50,730);
pdf_close($pdf);
?>
```

error is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFlibException' with message 'Function must not be called in 'object' scope' in /var/www/Sample/sam.php:4 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/Sample/sam.php(4): pdf_begin_page(Resource id #2, 595, 842) 
#1 {main} thrown in /var/www/Sample/sam.php on line 4
```

Comment: That's nearly the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997627/pdflib-giving-an-uncaught-exception-error does this resolve your problem?

Comment: Hope this helps you http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-open-file.php

Comment: @Xavjer there also problem not solved it is looks like unanswered question

Comment: Please update your question to your new code and error... because the first error came because u used depreciated pdf_begin_page and not PDF_begin_page_ext

Comment: there is no function like PDF_begin_page_ext in eclipse, am using eclipse
in the above code it is not showing syntax error and you suggested function is not there

Comment: from the docs [`pdf_open_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-open-file.php) - This function is deprecated since PDFlib version 6, use [`pdf_begin_document()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-begin-document.php) instead.

Comment: @Sean there is now function with pdf_begin_document() also.

Comment: @sean if possible can you post some sample code please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pdf_open_file() returns with an error which is ignored/not checked.

When you try to do pdf_begin_page() although there is no valid open file PDFlib throws an exception.

Here the explanation from the PDFlib manual:

PDFlib application must obey certain structural rules which are easy to understand. For example, you obviously begin a document before ending it. PDFlib enforces correct ordering of function calls with a strict scoping system. The scope definitions can be found in the PDFlib manual (Table 1.3). All API function descriptions specify the allowed scope for each function. Calling a function outside of the allowed scopes results in an exception. You can query the current scope with the scope keward of PDF_get_option().

Also it is recommended to use the current examples delivered with PDFlib as a starting point, there you can see the current API used with proper errorhandling.

A complete PHP example would look like this:

```
<?php
/* $Id: hello.php,v 1.20 2013/01/24 16:58:59 rp Exp $
 *
 * PDFlib client: hello example in PHP
 */

try {
    $p = new PDFlib();

    # This means we must check return values of load_font() etc.
    $p->set_option("errorpolicy=return");

    /* all strings are expected as utf8 */
    $p->set_option("stringformat=utf8");

    /*  open new PDF file; insert a file name to create the PDF on disk */
    if ($p->begin_document("", "") == 0) {
        die("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
    }

    $p->set_info("Creator", "hello.php");
    $p->set_info("Author", "Rainer Schaaf");
    $p->set_info("Title", "Hello world (PHP)!");

    $p->begin_page_ext(595, 842, "");

    $font = $p->load_font("Helvetica-Bold", "unicode", "");
    if ($font == 0) {
        die("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
    }

    $p->setfont($font, 24.0);
    $p->set_text_pos(50, 700);
    $p->show("Hello world!");
    $p->continue_text("(says PHP)");
    $p->end_page_ext("");

    $p->end_document("");

    $buf = $p->get_buffer();
    $len = strlen($buf);

    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Length: $len");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=hello.pdf");
    print $buf;

}
catch (PDFlibException $e) {
    die("PDFlib exception occurred in hello sample:\n" .
        "[" . $e->get_errnum() . "] " . $e->get_apiname() . ": " .
        $e->get_errmsg() . "\n");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}

$p = 0;
?>
```